# C# linq left out join does not work using DefaultIfEmpty

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to c# and I have a query for using left join in LINQ.

I have two data source - one is categories collection, one is products collection. I want to join this two data source together so that I can have result like this :

```
Category Name (Fruit) - Product Name ( peach)- Source ( QLD,NSW).
```

Please note I have Source as List collection inside products collection.

I have two problems here:

1. When I use `DefaultIfEmpty`, I cannot set correct reference to null `Source` collection if `Souce` does not exist - I can however reference to a Product Name if it does not exist to a meaningful string say "Does not exist". Anybody can help to show how to put a empty string if left join cannot find Source for a product ?
2. I cannot find a way to output `Category Name` - like `Fruit ,Vegetables`  in final result although i can do it in `group join`, any idea of how to do that ?

I attached my code here.

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public List<string> Source;
}

class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

```
// Specify the first data source.
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>()
{ 
    new Category(){Name="Beverages", ID=001},
    new Category(){ Name="Condiments", ID=002},
    new Category(){ Name="Vegetables", ID=003},
    new Category() {  Name="Grains", ID=004},
    new Category() {  Name="Fruit", ID=005}            
};

// Specify the second data source.
List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
{
     new Product{Name="Cola",CategoryID=001,  Source = new List<string> {"NSW","VIC","QLD"} },  
     new Product{Name="Mustard", CategoryID=002 ,  Source = new List<string> {"NSW","VIC","SA"} },
     new Product{Name="Pickles", CategoryID=002 ,  Source = new List<string> {"NSW","VIC","NT"} },
     new Product{Name="Carrots", CategoryID=003 ,  Source = new List<string> {"NSW","VIC","TAS"} },
     new Product{Name="Bok Choy", CategoryID=003 ,  Source = new List<string> {"NSW","VIC","ACT"} },
     new Product{Name="Eggplant", CategoryID=003 ,  Source = new List<string> {"QLD","NSW"} },
     new Product{Name="Broccoli", CategoryID=003 ,  Source = new List<string> {"QLD,SA"} },
     new Product{Name="Peaches", CategoryID=005 ,  Source = new List<string> {"NSW","VIC","NZ"} },
     new Product{Name="Melons", CategoryID=005,  Source = new List<string> {"NSW","VIC"} },
};
```

the following code does not work for `left join` in LINQ:

```
void LeftOuterJoin()
{
   var leftOuterQuery =
       from category in categories
       join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID into prodGroup          
       select prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new Product()
       { Name = "Nothing!", CategoryID = category.ID})
       ;

    // Store the count of total items (for demonstration only). 
    int totalItems = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Left Outer Join:");

    // A nested foreach statement  is required to access group items 
    foreach (var prodGrouping in leftOuterQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nGroup count: {0}", prodGrouping.Count());

        // Intellisense does not show category name  if I use prodGrouping.Name 
         //and want to get categorhy name since left join produce hierarchy data 
         //why category name is not showing up - I am itinerate from 1st loop ??
        foreach (var item in prodGrouping)
        {
            totalItems++;
            Console.WriteLine("  {0,-10}{1}", item.Name, item.CategoryID);

            foreach (var s in item.Source)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Souce state: {0}", s.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Hi Marcin, I changed my original code it works but give  me duplicate records, do you know why ?

```
 void LeftOuterJoin()
    {
        // Create the query. 
        var leftOuterQuery =
           from category in categories
           join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID into prodGroup
           from prodG in prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()       
            select new
            {
                Category = category.Name,
                //Products = products.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                Products = from prod2 in prodGroup
                           orderby prod2.Name
                           select prod2
            };


        Console.WriteLine("Left Outer Join:");

        // A nested foreach statement  is required to access group items 
        foreach (var item in leftOuterQuery)
        {                 

             Console.WriteLine("  {0,-10}", item.Category);
             foreach ( var p in item.Products)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("ProductName: {0}", p.Name);
                 foreach (var s in p.Source)
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("SourceName: {0}", s.ToString());

                 }
             }                   


        }

    }
```

I want to get result like this:

```
  Group Beverages:1
  Cola      1
  Souce state: NSW
  Souce state: VIC
  Souce state: QLD

 Group : Condiments
  Mustard   2
   Souce state: NSW
   Souce state: VIC
   Souce state: SA
 Pickles   2
  Souce state: NSW
  Souce state: VIC
  Souce state: NT
```

But I got result like this:

```
Beverages
 ProductName: Cola
 SourceName: NSW
 SourceName: VIC
 SourceName: QLD

Condiments
 ProductName: Mustard
 SourceName: NSW
 SourceName: VIC
 SourceName: SA    
 ProductName: Pickle
 SourceName: NSW
 SourceName: VIC
 SourceName: NT

Condiments
 ProductName: Mustard
 SourceName: NSW
 SourceName: VIC
 SourceName: SA
 ProductName: Pickle
 SourceName: NSW
 SourceName: VIC
 SourceName: NT
```

Comment: possibly you need use `from pg in prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(..) select pg` instead of `select prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(...)`

Comment: if I use from pg in prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(..) select pg ... it will not give me category information .. I will get flatten data... Alan

Comment: This is result I want to see:

Comment: this is result should look like: Group Vegetables: 4
  Carrots   3
Souce state: NS
Souce state: VI
Souce state: TA
  Bok Choy  3
Souce state: NS
Souce state: VI
Souce state: AC
  Eggplant  3
Souce state: QL
Souce state: NS
  Broccoli  3
Souce state: QL

Group Grains: 1
  Nothing!  4
  Source not exist

Comment: Group Vegetables: 4 --> 4 is count of product within group ( There are 4 products in Vegetables cateogry namely Carrots,Bok Choy,Egg plant, Broccoli. Carrots 3, Bok Choy 3 --> 3 is Category ID Vegetables category  has CategoryID as 3

Comment: @alanyao, so just select what you want

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve, but to get `left outer join` using LINQ you need to use `join ... into` and `from ....DefaultIfEmpty()`.

You're using `select ....DefaultIfEmpty()`, which is not exactly what you need.

```
var leftOuterQuery =
    from category in categories
    join prod in products on category.ID equals prod.CategoryID into prodGroup
    from products in prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()       
    select new
    {
        Category = category.Name,
        Products = products.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    }
```

Comment: Hi Marcin.. thanks for your quick reply. what I want to achieve is I want to get a result like this: Category Vegetables has 4 products: Carrots  3 Source: NSW,VIC,TAS  / Bok Choy  3 Source: NSW,VIC,ACT / Eggplant  3  Source: QLD,SW / Broccoli  3 Source:QLD --> please note Number 3 is CategoryID for each product!  /// Category Grains has 0 products, "Nothing,No product in this Category" Source: "No product, No Source State"  /// .. I just cannot assing a string for List of collection of Product for 'Grains" Category becase 'Source' is a collection , Not a string ! ... Alan

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and neat extension for left outer join using linq published here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/724333/Left-Outer-Join-extension-for-Entity-Framework
I think this may help you.

Comment: Hi Marcin.. could you provide complete code to show how to not only have Category infomation but also products details under each category - that is if there is a match ( including product name and product source) ??, if there is no match, just print Category name but for product name and its relevant source , rather to have it as null, print some text ie " No product", "No Source state" ?

Comment: Hi Marcin.. could you provide complete code to show how to not only Print Category infomation but also Print products details under each category - ( including product name and product source) that is if there is a match  ??, if there is no product match for a category , just print Category name but for product name and its relevant source , rather to have it as null, print some text ie " No product", "No Source state" ? I just want some result similar to SQL left join but C# left join in LINQ sound too difficult for me to get what I want... anybody please help this one ...